# Einstein Bot get value from dynamic Menu

Tags: apex, einstein, bots

I have been created a dynamic menu by using an apex action that retrieves information from my Assets. It works fine, but my question is how to capture the value when the user clicks above some option and pass it as a parameter to another action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a dynamic menu an option will be given to set the variable you want to store the value in. You can create a custom bot variable type of object to store the value that the user selected.

[image]

Below is a sample Invocable Method that accepts object as a parameter.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I have done that, but how do I pass the object as a parameter to call another apex action? It allows only String as a parameter as far as I know.

Comment: You are able to pass object as parameter as long as you have declared a InvocableVariable of type of the object that you are trying to pass.

Comment: Thanks!
That's exactly what I needed.